# \includegraphics giving error

Tags: graphics, compilation-error

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{figs/bogie_acc.jpg} 
        \caption{Rolling of coach in oscillation trial and SIMPACK}
    \label{FIG:1}
\end{figure}
```

> Argument of @tempa has an extra }.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The code you show seems correct. Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the error, please?

Comment: @MadyYuvi that is unrelated (I would guess:-)

Comment: make sure that you have loaded graphicx not graphic (but that would give a different error) please try to make a small complete document that demonstrates the error, are you sure the `\@tempa` error comes from this code? Also do nt use `[!h]` except in very special circumstances.